# How to use a Macbook to duplicate an entire Windows disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows, ssd

I am visiting my in-laws soon and they have an old Dell laptop that is problematic. It has a very slow 5400RPM HDD that I plan to replace with a SSD of the same logical size (e.g. 1Tb HDD to 1Tb SSD).

I know there are various products that can do this on the Dell laptop itself and those are my fallback plan, but I would prefer to use my M1 Macbook Air if I can. I have an appropriate dock that I can take with me that can deal with physical connections to disk enclosures, so that's all fine.

The problem is software. Does anyone know of software I can run on a M1 Mac that will handle the duplication and leave me with a SSD disk that is bootable on the Dell laptop when I am done. I don't think WinClone will do it as that's all about bootcamp from the look of things.

Comment: Running `dd` may work. It will just take a (long) time to mirror 1 TB, but that's a problem any solution will have.

Comment: That's true. The disks are nowhere near full so I'm after something that won't take ages copying nulls, ideally...

Comment: A speedup requires knowledge of the data to be copied. Considering the lack of NTFS write support on macOS (at least not without 3rd party software) this might be a challenge.

Comment: `dd` will work as @nohillside suggests especially if you access the raw device `/dev/rdiskXX` (notice the “r” prefacing the `diskXX` device identifier).  However being that this is a 5400 RPM drive, the very best you’ll get is 6GB/s transfer rate (in a vacuum, going down hill).  This will take forever!  You might have better results putting that HDD into a PC and clone it with it being attached to the SATA bus and booting from a Live Linux CD/USB

Comment: @Allan I think you & nohillside are right. If one of you wanted to put that into an answer, I'd probably accept it. I've been working on the live Linux approach as my "plan B" and its something I've done before, but was curious if there was an approach that would work well from a Mac, as I'm going to be taking that with me anyway to have a nice screen to research any issues from...